# Create arrays from JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

I have some data which looks like this:

```
{
  "obj":
  [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "age": "24"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "age": "17"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need to do is to create 2 arrays from it.

For example:

```
namelist[];
agelist[];
```

so the result would be:

```
namelist: ['name1', 'name2'];

agelist: [24, 17];
```

My question is, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this ES6 code, and use the unitary plus for getting the ages as numbers. Assuming your object is stored in variable `data`:

```
var namelist = data.obj.map( o => o.name );
var agelist = data.obj.map( o => +o.age );
```

```js
var data = {
    "obj": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "age": "24"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "age": "17"
        }
    ]
};

var namelist = data.obj.map( o => o.name );
var agelist = data.obj.map( o => +o.age );

console.log(namelist);
console.log(agelist);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var namelist = [];
var agelist = [];
for(var i in obj.obj){
    namelist.push(obj.obj[i].name);
    agelist.push(obj.obj[i].age);
}

console.log(namelist, agelist);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what U wanted ?

```
var zz={
    "obj": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "age": "24"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "age": "17"
        }
    ]
}

namelist=[];
agelist=[];
zz.obj.forEach(function(rec){
  namelist.push(rec.name);
  agelist.push(rec.age);
})

console.log(namelist,agelist)
```

Comment: Can agelist array be integer instead of strings ?

Comment: @MarkcceEros you can use push(parseInt(rec,age)) and it will be a number

Answer (score 0):

Make use of jquery map function or otherwise you can loop over the object and push it into array using javascript for loop and use the `push()` function. Refer [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/36774966#36774966)

Jquery

```js
var data = {
    "obj": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "age": "24"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "age": "17"
        }
    ]
}

var name = $.map(data.obj, function(value, index) {
    return value.name;
});
var age = $.map(data.obj, function(value, index) {
    return value.age;
});

console.log(name);
console.log(age);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```js
var data = {
        "obj": [
            {
                "name": "name1",
                "age": "24"
            },
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "age": "17"
            }
        ]
    }
    var names = [], ages=[];
    data.obj.forEach(function(value, index) {

        names.push(value.name);
        ages.push(value.age);
    });
console.log(names,ages);
```

Comment: Where did you see a jQuery reference?

Comment: @Andreas I understand the is no jquery tag, i.e why I also added to my answer on how to approach a javascript solution. But since you emphasised on it, I edited my answer. And its OP choice to use jquery if he wishes to, I just gave an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
return [value];
});


console.log(arr);
```

if you are not using Jquery then:

```
var arr = Object.keys(myObj).map(function (key) 
 { return obj[key]; 
});`
```

Comment: 1. There is no jQuery tag; 2. What is `myObj`? 3. The first would create an array of arrays

Comment: myObj is the name of the object he wishes to convert

Comment: Then your solution makes no sense at all. Either he has to call the snippet for each entry in `"obj"` which would only return an array of values or if he calls it on the object which `"obj"` is a property of, it would result in an array which contains the value of `"obj"` (an array of objects)